# How to output clickable links in test tables in the latest FitNesse version '20140201'

Tags: automated-tests, fitnesse, acceptance-testing

I want to display in a FitNesse test table some clickable links. So I had created some FitNesse fixture methods that return HTML links. This worked fine in FitNesse version `release 20110104`

Like for example:

```
public String getCanonical() {
    return "<a href=" + mCanonical + ">" + mCanonical + "</a>";
}
```

However **after upgrading the FitNesse server** to the latest release it does **no longer render the HTML tags**. Is it possible to enable rendering of HTML tags again in the latest FitNesse version `20140201` ?

I have a lot of data-driven tests where outputing some clickable links was really convenient while reviewing test results, because in case of doubts I could quickly jump to the tested URL.

I already tried using [FitNesse Link formatting](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.QuickReferenceGuide#LinksAndREFERENCES) but this does not seem to work inside the test tables.

Any solutions or workarounds for this? I am tempted to rollback FitNesse to the old version if I cannot find a solution for this. (old version works all fine for me)

Answer (score 0):

What I found out is that FitNesse is picky on what HTML elements it allow to go into the output HTML table directly and what it escapes ([a regular expression is used](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/src/fitnesse/html/HtmlUtil.java), based on the HTML spec I'm told). Looking at the code it does not allow `<a.. ></a>` so this would explain your problem.

My fixtures output HTML in various situations and that works great, as long as I enclose the HTML elements in a `<div>` `</div>` pair. So for your method it would be:

```
public String getCanonical() {
    return "<div><a href=" + mCanonical + ">" + mCanonical + "</a></div>";
}
```